# Ping через прокси c#

Tags: c#, proxy, ping

Здравствуйте! Интересует как получить пинг до сервера через прокси в c#. 
Пробовал через xNet - записывал время до запроса и после. разницу принимал за Ping. Но путь явно не верный. т.к. пинг получился в 800ms(без прокси), хотя через cmd - получаю 160.

решил что трабл в xNet - все таки это надстройка над WebRequest. 
Сделал через WebRequest - тот же результат.

Единственно решение, которое вижу- устанавливать прокси для всех соединение, а после бросать Ping. Если это действительно единственное решение - то подскажите как это сделать?

Comment: А прокси у вас какая ? через большинство прокси ICMP протокол (на котором основан ping) не проходит. И собственно какое время вам интересно. Если вы делаете WebRequest - то получаете время ответа web-сервера, которое разумеется больше, чем ответ на стандартный ping ядром ОС

Comment: Прокси HTTPS с авторизацией. Я делаю запрос к 2ip.ru:8001(их javascript для проверки пинга осуществляет такой же запрос)
Там ответ El Condor Pasa и все. Без разметки, и прочего. Так что принебрегая лагами сервера - можно считать что результат будет близок  результату пинга.

Comment: Вопрос в том, как получить время ожидания ответа?

Comment: При том мы ведь может ограничить время ответа Timeout'ом. Значит где-то это время хранится. Как бы его получить?

Comment: Ping, который настоящий ICMP, никак не связан с прокси, только маршрутизация. Не будет время одинаковым, и даже похожим не будет. Не забывайте про время, необходимое на шифрование, авторизацию, отклик прокси, отклик web-сервера, все это происходит не мгновенно. Ваш Ping в любом случае будет медленнее и у вас еще очень неплохая разница получилась с учетом прокси и SSL.

Comment: немного разобрался в вопросе. Вообщем мне нужно получить время соединения. А не общее время запроса, которое включает время соедиения, время отправка, время ожидания ответа, время приема.

Comment: По поводу пинга я понял что не получится его отправить через прокси. 
теперь я пытаюсь дернуть пустую страницу с сервера. И важно получить именно время соединения, без времени ожидания ответа.